# Pulling data out of a string formatted like XML with <keys>values</keys>

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsstring, nsdictionary

What is the best way to take a NSString and turn it into NSDictionary with NSArray and NSString values that correspond with their keys.

The NSString is like this, it has some random spacing in it, but it's structured well to become an NSDictionary:

```
<data>
  <Groups>
    <Group1>
      <Name>Beginners</Name>
      <Description>Beginner Only</Description>
      <Members>
        <Member1>
          <FirstName>Bobby</FirstName>
          <LastName>Simmons</LastName>
        </Member1>    
        <Member2>
          <FirstName>Johnny</FirstName>    
          <LastName>Rocket</LastName>   
        </Member2>
      </Members>
    </Group1>
    <Group2>
      <Name>Expert</Name>      
      <Description>All the experts</Description>      
      <Members>
        <Member1>
          <firstName>Julie</FirstName>
          <LastName>Bloom</LastName>
        </Member1>
      </Members>
    </Group2>
  </Groups>
</data>
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Learn libxml2. Learn to love it. It will be your guide through rough times.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSXMLDocument -- it's a fairly easy to use high-level Cocoa API. It'll parse this into a tree of NSXMLElement objects that you can fairly easily traverse.

It also supports XPath, which takes a little while to learn but is a really powerful way to grab stuff out of XML, like "the firstName and lastName fields of every Member element".